# PHP for member sign up issues on submit

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, post

I've been putting together my first attempt at anything PHP...and it doesnt work...
Basically when I click 'Submit' it just changed the window to display the php code, and submits nothing to mysql.

This is what I have.

```
<?php
require('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//Perform the verification

$email1 = $_POST['email1'];
$email2 = $_POST['email2'];
$pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

if($email1 == $email2){
if($pass1 == $pass2){
//all good carry on

$name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$lname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
$uname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$email1 = mysql_escape_string($email1);
$email2 = mysql_escape_string($email2);
$pass1 = mysql_escape_string($pass1);
$pass2 = mysql_escape_string($pass2);



mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `lname`, `uname`, `email`, `pass`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$lname', '$uname', '$email1', '$pass1')");




}else{
echo "Sorry, your passwords do not match.<br />";
exit();
}
}else{
echo "Sorry, your email addresses do not match.<br /><br />";


}else{

$form = <<<EOT
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
First Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" name="email1" /><br />
Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email2" /><br />
Password: <input type="text" name="pass1" /><br />
Confirm Password: <input type="text" name="pass2" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />

</form>


EOT;

}

?>
```

I'll add that the only way I could see the form was to copy the 'form' into a separate html file.

Any help wold be great and if you need more info just let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your server isn't setup to execute PHP. Have you tried a basic PHP script with phpinfo()?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home/r*****2/******************.co.uk/tut/register.php on line 40

This is the error i am now getting.

Answer (score 2):

If you can see php code in your browser, your web server isn't configured properly and so this has nothing to do with php itself.

Comment: The form should not be visible as you are not displaying it. You need to configure your web server to execute .php files with PHP. Then, to display the form, you will need to echo the form after defining it (ie "echo $form;")

Comment: that may have been my bad, sorry. just tried viewing it from another source and i am getting this -
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home/r*****2/******************.co.uk/tut/register.php on line 40

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass the `id` field as `null`, just leave it out.  Assuming of course the `id` field is set to primary index and autoincrement, which it should be.

Answer (score 0):

turns out it was simply because i had mismatched my mysql_connect details.
Thanksfor the hints guys! wouldnt have figured it out otherwise.